# Filtering data using constraints in Datastage Transformer

Tags: datastage

In Datastage, I have an INTEGER field from a Seq File 0, in a transformer i wanted to write a constraint that if the Source data from the seq file is <> 0 or <> Numeric (numbers) then it should be written in seq file 2 and other Numeric data and 0 into Seq File 1 sequential file.

Please help me out.

Seq File 0 ->Transformer(Constraint) -> Seq File 1 (0 or Other Numerics) and 
                                     -> Seq File 2 (Blanks and Non-numeric)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [num](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.serverjob.dev.doc/topics/r_dsvjbref_Num_Function.html) Function or [alpha](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.serverjob.dev.doc/topics/r_dsvjbref_Alpha_Function.html) function to check wether it is a number or alphanumeric value. You may have to handle the empty case separately.